# Synapse Notebook Password visible on Runtime

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I have created Synapse Notebook in which I am passing parameters for secrets like password. These secrets are in KeyVault, being passed to the Notebook as parameters. Ideally I would expect that these secrets are not visible to developers. However when the pipeline is triggered or in debug mode, the values of the secrets are visible in plain text in the pipeline output. In the notebook, a runtime cell is created in which parameters for password are visible in plain text. How do I change the notebook and pipeline so that secrets are not dumped out as plain text.

In the Web activity I am already using secure output.

Answer (score -2):

Found the solution. Use TokenLibrary in Synapse ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python)):

```
TokenLibrary.getSecret("<AZURE KEY VAULT NAME>", "<SECRET KEY>" [, <LINKED SERVICE NAME>])
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)